# Referencing version of a dependency from parent pom in child pom

Tags: maven, maven-3

I have a parent pom that define a dependency in dependencyManagement bloc like this

```
    <dependencyManagement>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.tibco.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>com.tibco.bw.palette.shared</artifactId>
            <version>6.1.100</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</dependencyManagement>
```

In a child pom I'm using the dependency like this

```
  <dependencies>
<dependency>
  <groupId>com.tibco.plugins</groupId>
  <artifactId>com.tibco.bw.palette.shared</artifactId>
  <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
```

the problem is when I open the project is a custom Eclipse IDE, I have this error, it can't understand that the version is in parent pom

[image]

I need some way to reference the version from the parent pom in the child pom without redefining it

thank you

Comment: Can you move tibco plugin artifact directly to the dependency section of parent pom.xml from dependency management. Besides, import the project as Maven project in Eclipse.

Comment: the project is imported as maven project I can see maven icone, I want to keep dependencies centralized in dependencyManagement, any way to reference the version ? 
thanks for replay

Comment: You can add dependency version in parent pom under properties
    <properties>
        <test.version>X.X</test.version>
    </properties> and reference that with place holders in child. Actually, you can also omit project properties outside of parent which are the same, as they will be inherited from parent.

Comment: Your approach with the dependencyManagement is completely correct and Eclipse usually understands that. I guess that your Eclipse needs some "refreshment", like ALT+F5 or restart. Furthermore, try to run a build on your project (e.g. `clean verify`), this often resolves synchronisation issues.

Comment: Or you need to check if you have correct parent/child relations in your project...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this ...

In your parent pom

```
<groupId>my.project</groupId>
<artifactId>myproject-parent</artifactId>
<version>MYPROJECT-1.0</version>
<packaging>pom</packaging>
<properties>
    <com.tibco.bw.palette.shared.version>6.1.100</com.tibco.bw.palette.shared.version>
</properties>
<dependencyManagement>
  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.tibco.plugins</groupId>
      <artifactId>com.tibco.bw.palette.shared</artifactId>
      <version>${com.tibco.bw.palette.shared.version}</version>
      <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>
</dependencyManagement>
```

Then in your child pom

```
<parent>
    <groupId>my.project</groupId>
    <artifactId>myproject-parent</artifactId>
    <version>MYPROJECT-1.0</version>
    <relativePath>..</relativePath>
</parent>

<groupId>my.project.child</groupId>
<artifactId>myproject-child</artifactId>
<version>MYPROJECT-1.0</version>

<dependencies>
  <dependency>
    <groupId>com.tibco.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>com.tibco.bw.palette.shared</artifactId>
  </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

It's important that you have your parent / child relationship set-up correctly. Also be aware that `dependencyManagement` only works one level in the maven hierarchy (i.e it'll not work on "grand children")

Answer (score 0):

adding dependency version in parent pom under properties  X.X  and reference that with place holders in child. Actually, you can also omit project properties outside of parent which are the same, as they will be inherited from parent. – from WhoCares